# If $R$ is a ring, $x^3\in Z(R)$ and $x^2\in Z(R)$ then $x\in Z(R)$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is this true and why?

If $R$ is a ring, $x^3\in Z(R)$ and $x^2\in Z(R)$  then $x\in Z(R)$ .

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: @ Branimir Ćaćić: This is an element of the proof which I can't understand and that is why I am asking for help. I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know how.

Comment: Let's start by writing down definitions.

Comment: Oh, and the problem mysteriously changed, too ...

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

There is a counter-example in the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices over a field.  However, the result is true if $R$ is a domain, so think about zero divisors.